# Vuetify validation using multiple rules

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to assign multiple rules to validate input? For example I have two rules:

```
alphaRule: [
      v => /[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(v) || 'Field must only contain letters'
    ],
requiredRule: [
               v => !!v || "required field"
            ]
```

And I have number of controls. Some of them need only requiredRules, some - only alphaRule, but some - combination of alphaRule and requiredRule.

Can I combine it together?

something like

```
:rules = "alphaRule, requiredRule"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to leave both variables, you can just work with them like with JS arrays.

```
:rules = "alphaRule.concat(requiredRule)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I need

Comment: how about  if we want to combine 3 or more rules?

Comment: @noel293, first.concat(second).concat(third), i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding the rules into the array:

```
:rules = "[alphaRule, requiredRule].flat()"
```

Answer (score -1):

this works for me

```
v-bind:rules="[mr.required, mr.counter]"
```

and this is the rules:

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer do not explains in detail.